# Minitest Issues Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, minitest

I'm reading the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and following along. I'm having problems however right when trying to do some testing.

```
[fran@fran-desktop twitter-clone]$ bundle exec rake test
/media/Data.II/Dropbox/Web Development/odin-project/3. Ruby on Rails/twitter-clone/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rake db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /media/Data.II/Dropbox/Web Development/odin-project/3. Ruby on Rails/twitter-clone/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.
/home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- guard (LoadError)
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/guard-minitest-2.4.4/lib/minitest/guard_minitest_plugin.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:91:in `block in load_plugins'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `load_plugins'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:114:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:56:in `block in autorun'
```

I run `rake db:migrate` (even thought I haven't yet created any migration) and now the error is the following:

```
[fran@fran-desktop twitter-clone]$ rake db:migrate
   (1340.1ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar NOT NULL) 
   (0.1ms)  select sqlite_version(*)
   (143.3ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
[fran@fran-desktop twitter-clone]$ bundle exec rake test
   (526.7ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar NOT NULL) 
   (0.2ms)  select sqlite_version(*)
   (243.3ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")
   (0.4ms)  SELECT version FROM "schema_migrations"
   (219.4ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('0')
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
/home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- guard (LoadError)
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/guard-minitest-2.4.4/lib/minitest/guard_minitest_plugin.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/fran/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:91:in `block in load_plugins'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:85:in `load_plugins'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:114:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.5.1/lib/minitest.rb:56:in `block in autorun'
```

This is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'

group :test do 
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'mini_backtrace'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end


end
```

What could it be ? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're using the `guard-minitest` gem, please see the first line of [the Install section of its README](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest#install)

Namely:

> Please be sure to have Guard installed before you continue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, to remove guard temporarily: edit your Gemfile and comment out the guard line:

```
# gem 'mini_backtrace'
```

Try this, to sync the test database:

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

Try this, to verify that you can connect to the development database:

```
bundle exec rake db
```

Try this, to verify that you can connect to the test database:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db
```

If the steps all succeed, then here's how to fix guard:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'guard' # NOTE: this is necessary in newer versions
  gem 'guard-minitest' 
end
```

Then run:

```
bundle
guard init minitest
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved it adding gem 'ruby-prof' and 'guard' to the test environment in the Gemfile.